# Graphics not working in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent, repaint

I am trying to mess around with some graphics in java, however i can't get it to work. The JFrame comes up with the button i created, but the JFrame is just gray with no red line that i want it to draw.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Shapes extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JButton button = new JButton("click");
public Shapes() {
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500, 500);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setSize(20, 20);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(button);
    repaint();
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Shapes s = new Shapes();   
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.drawLine(5, 10, 10, 20);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == button){
        repaint();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't paint directly on a `JFrame` use a `JPanel` instead.

Comment: If i change it to JPanel, when i start the program, the program just ends itself after 1-2 seconds without showing me the JPanel. Also, i can't use repaint() with JPanel. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I posted an answer going into more detail

Comment: 1) As @BitNinja states, you paint in your JPanel, and you add your JPanel to a JFrame that is then displayed. 2) You should always use the `@Override` annotation before a method that you're trying to override. If you did that, you'd find that JFrame does not have a `paintComponent(...)` method.

Comment: Thanks for helping me :) i'm starting to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1). You don't really want to do custom painting on a top-level container such as a `JFrame`. Instead you want to use a `JPanel`

```
class Panel extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.drawLine(5, 10, 10, 20);
    }
}
```

And add it to your `JFrame`: `add(new Panel());` (Or create an object if you want).

2). `setVisible(true);` should be the very last thing that you do while setting up your window. So change your constructor:

```
public Shapes() {
setSize(500, 500);
button.addActionListener(this);
button.setSize(20, 20);
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
add(button);
add(new Panel()) // added from part 1
repaint();
setVisible(true);
}
```

For more information go through the ["performing custom painting tutorials."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: 1+, but don't forget to recommend to call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method within your override.

Comment: Thank you all for taking your time and helping me :)